# remove margin / padding space from canvas

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am working on canvas object i created cylinder canvas object.

But I am getting white space from left,right,top & Bottom How to remove those. I tried adding css as below

CSS

```
canvas
{
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
}
```

Still it was not removing the white space.Any Suggestion / solution to remove the whitespace

Here is the fiddle [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/rAA8S/3/)  to see my canvas object

Thanks in advance
Maha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: http://jsfiddle.net/rAA8S/23/
Just move that yellow round to it's correct place.
Code changed:

```
var cx = 40;
var cy = 60;
```

it was

```
var cx = canvasWidth / 2;
var cy = canvasHeight / 2;
```

Witch makes it go to the center of the canvas. I moved it almost to the very left border, now only you need to move that yellow thing. I guess this is not written by you?

Comment: hi thanks for your reply but i tried it was not working

Comment: Do you want to delete whitespace from canvas, or from borders of canvas?

Comment: edited! Go check that link and tell me what more to do?